# How to remove if-else chain from Dart?

Tags: flutter, if-statement, dart

I have quite a huge if-else chain in a Flutter application which checks a bunch of conditions from a list of titles. I'm trying to figure out how to deal with such a chain without this series of if-else statements. Would a Map be suitable, or maybe a simple switch case?

```
if (listOfMaps[i]["title"] == "BPM LOW" && !activeAlarms.contains("BPM LOW")) {
            activeAlarms.add("BPM LOW");
          } else if (listOfMaps[i]["title"] == "BPM HIGH" && !activeAlarms.contains("BPM HIGH")) {
            activeAlarms.add("BPM HIGH");
          } else if (listOfMaps[i]["title"] == "PIP LOW" &&
              !activeAlarms.contains("PIP LOW")) {
            activeAlarms.add("PIP LOW");
          } else if (listOfMaps[i]["title"] == "PIP HIGH" &&
              !activeAlarms.contains("PIP HIGH")) {
            activeAlarms.add("PIP HIGH");
          }
```

Comment: Personally, I would save the result of `listOfMaps[i]["title"]` in a local variable before the first `if` to make it easier to read and save a lot of lookup in the array and map.

Comment: For what it's worth, 3 else-ifs is hardly a 'huge chain', especially if the different conditions are warranted.

Answer (score 1):

```dart
for (final data in listOfMaps) {
  final title = data["title"];
  if (!activeAlarms.contains(title)) {
    activeAlarms.add(title);
  }
}
```

Comment: Note that this isn't exactly the same if there are other possible values for `listOfMaps[i]['title']`.

Answer (score 0):

```
List activeAlarms = ["BPM HIGH"];
List listOfMaps = [
  {"title": "BPM LOW"},
  {"title": "BPM HIGH"},
  {"title": "PIP LOW"},
  {"title": "PIP HIGH"},
];
print('listOfMaps:');
print(listOfMaps);

print('activeAlarms before:');
print(activeAlarms);

listOfMaps.forEach((e) {
  activeAlarms.singleWhere((element) => (element == e["title"]), orElse: () {
    activeAlarms.add(e["title"]);
  });
});

print('activeAlarms after:');
print(activeAlarms);
```

Here's some code.
And output:

```
flutter: listOfMaps:  
flutter: [{title: BPM LOW}, {title: BPM HIGH}, {title: PIP LOW}, {title: PIP HIGH}]  
flutter: activeAlarms before:  
flutter: [BPM HIGH]  
flutter: activeAlarms after:  
flutter: [BPM HIGH, BPM LOW, PIP LOW, PIP HIGH]
```